# How I follow a user by requests of Python in Mastodon API?

Tags: python

I cannot follow in the API.

code:

```
#!/user/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import requests
    url = 'https://[domain]/api/v1/follows'
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer KEYXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'}

    ID = 'id@domain'
    payload = {'uri': ID}
    res = json.loads(requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload)).text)
    print res
```

result:

```
{u'error': u'Record not found'}
```

the domain, the ID, the Authorization key is usable.
what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation specifies the usage of form data, and not json. Your request should look like this:

`requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)`